# How can i show all categories using wp query?

Tags: query

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query(); ?>
<?php $recent->query('cat=1&showposts=2'); ?>
```

With what can i replace cat=1 to show posts from all the categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to remove that category from the query so you would have`<?php $recent->query('showposts=2'); ?>` you can also take a look at completely custom queries [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query). 
`

Answer (score 4):

Might I also suggest that instead of using `showposts=2` you use `posts_per_page=2`, since `showposts` [has been deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).